# How to moq Entity Framework SaveChangesAsync?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, async-await, moq

```
Mock<IDbContext> dbContext;

[TestFixtureSetUp]
public void SetupDbContext()
{
    dbContext = new Mock<IDbContext>();
    dbContext.Setup(c => c.SaveChanges()).Verifiable();
    dbContext.Setup(c => c.SaveChangesAsync()).Verifiable();
    dbContext.Setup(c => c.Customers.Add(It.IsAny<Customer>()))
             .Returns(It.IsAny<Customer>()).Verifiable();
}

[Test]
public async Task AddCustomerAsync()
{
    //Arrange
    var repository = new EntityFrameworkRepository(dbContext.Object);
    var customer = new Customer() { FirstName = "Larry", LastName = "Hughes" };

    //Act
    await repository.AddCustomerAsync(customer);

    //Assert
    dbContext.Verify(c => c.Customers.Add(It.IsAny<Customer>()));
    dbContext.Verify(c => c.SaveChangesAsync());
}

[Test]
public void AddCustomer()
{
    //Arrange
    var repository = new EntityFrameworkRepository(dbContext.Object);
    var customer = new Customer() { FirstName = "Larry", LastName = "Hughes" };

    //Act
    repository.AddCustomer(customer);

    //Assert
    dbContext.Verify(c => c.Customers.Add(It.IsAny<Customer>()));
    dbContext.Verify(c => c.SaveChanges());
}
```

And here's what I want to test:

```
public class EntityFrameworkRepository
{
    private readonly IDbContext DBContext;

    public EntityFrameworkRepository(IDbContext context)
    {
        DBContext = context;
    }

    public async Task AddCustomerAsync(Customer customer)
    {
        DBContext.Customers.Add(customer);
        await DBContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public void AddCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        DBContext.Customers.Add(customer);
        DBContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

`AddCustomers` test passes.

`AddCustomersAsync` test fails, I keep getting a NullReferenceException after calling `await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()`.

> at
>   MasonOgCRM.DataAccess.EF.EntityFrameworkRepository.d__2.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Users\Mason\Desktop\Repositories\masonogcrm\src\DataAccess.EFRepository\EntityFrameworkRepository.cs:line
>   43

I can't see anything that's null in my code. `DbContext` is not null. The equivalent test of `AddCustomers` which is identical with the exception of not being async runs as expected. I suspect I haven't performed a correct setup of `SaveChangesAsync` in `SetupDBContext()` but I don't know what to do to fix it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right the problem occurs because one of your setups incorrect :: `dbContext.Setup(c => c.SaveChangesAsync()).Verifiable();`.

The method return a `Task` and you forgot to return a `Task` therefore `null` returns.

You can remove `dbContext.Setup(c => c.SaveChangesAsync()).Verifiable();` or 
change the setup to something like:

```
dbContext.Setup(c => c.SaveChangesAsync()).Returns(() => Task.Run(() =>{})).Verifiable();
```

Comment: Got it. `SaveChangesAsync` actually returns a `Task<int>` so I modified the setup to this: `dbContext.Setup(c => c.SaveChangesAsync()).Returns(() => Task.Run(() => { return 1; })).Verifiable();` and that did the trick!

Comment: @mason you welcome :-) In my opinion I'd remove this setup, It doesn't give you anything unless you use `VerifyAll`

Answer (score 12):

You could use

```
dataContext.Setup(x => x.SaveChangesAsync()).ReturnsAsync(1);
```

and

```
dataContext.Verify(x=>x.SaveChangesAsync());
```

Comment: I'm using .Net Core 2.2 SDK, didn't work with out the CancellationToken parameter. 
                                                                                          mockMessageContext.Setup(m => m.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(5);

Comment: am using .netcore 3.1 and agree that it no requires cancellation token. but my verify calls are failing.  mockDb.Verify(a => a.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()),Times.Exactly(2)); Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: a => a.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())

Comment: .net 5 also requires It.IsAny<CancellationToken>() to verify SaveChangesAsync.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
dbContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once());
```

Answer (score 0):

It may also require a cancellation token, so something like this should work:

```
dataContext.Setup(x => x.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(1);
```