# Unit Test OData V4 PUT action with XUnit and MOQ

Tags: unit-testing, xunit, asp.net-web-api-odata

My goal is to unit test the PUT action in an OData v4 controller.

I'm using MOQ for the Entity Framework 6 Context and NBuilder to build out the test data.

I am able to successfully test Get and Get(Id), but am unable to run asserts when I retrieve the HTTPActionResult from the PUT action.

I can see the HTTPActionResult returning an UpdatedODataResult object with an Entity property in debug mode, but I don't see a way to work with it at design time.

Does anyone know how to extract the returned Entity from the Async PUT action response?

Here is the code:

```
using Models;
using WebApp.DAL;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.OData;

namespace WebApp.Controllers.Api
{
    public class OrgsController : ODataController
    {
        private IWebAppDbContext db = new WebAppDbContext();

        public OrgsController()
        {
        }

        public OrgsController(IWebAppDbContext Context)
        {
           db = Context;
        }

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] long Key, Org Entity)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            if (Key != Entity.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.MarkAsModified(Entity);
            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!EntityExists(Key))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return Updated(Entity);
        }
        //...other actions omitted
    }
}
```

Here is my Unit Test code

```
[Theory, InlineData(5)]
public async Task Api_Put_Updates_Properties(long Id)
{            
    //arrange
    var mockedDbContext = MocksFactory.GetMockContext<WebAppDbContext>();
    mockedDbContext.Object.Orgs.AddRange(MocksFactory.GetMockData<Org>(10));                
    OrgsController _sut = new OrgsController(mockedDbContext.Object);
    Org beforeEntity = new Org
    {
        Id = Id,
        Name = "Put Org",
        TaxCountryCode = "PutUs",
        TaxNumber = "PutUs01"
    };

    //act
    IHttpActionResult actionResult = await _sut.Put(Id, beforeEntity); 

    //assert   
    Assert.NotNull(actionResult);
    //Assert.NotNull(actionResult.Entity);
    //Assert.Equal(Id, actionResult.Entity.Id);
    //Assert.Equal("Put Org", actionResult.Entity.Name);
}
```

Comment: How do `Updated` method looks like? Based on the code it seems that your assert should be: `verify(x => x.MarkAsModified(beforeEntity))`, `verify(x => x.SaveChangesAsync())`....

Comment: Ah, so use MOQ to confirm the EF methods are called vs. inspecting the updated entity in the response.  Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @Old Fox for the suggestion.  Here's what I ended up with:
*Note: I included in-line mock setup for explanation purposes.  I used this approach to create my factories in the production code: http://www.rhyous.com/2015/04/10/how-to-mock-an-entity-framework-dbcontext-and-its-dbset-properties/#comment-121594

This post also helped me piece together the Moq setup: [How to moq Entity Framework SaveChangesAsync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32793747/how-to-moq-entity-framework-savechangesasync)

Also, the link I referenced in the comments shows how to properly setup the GetEnumerator method.  The instructions on the MSDN page are incorrect.
The difference is subtle, but significant (that discovery cost me a week).  Make sure you set that piece up properly or your context will have an empty dbset (Orgs in this example).

```
[Theory, InlineData(1), InlineData(3), InlineData(5)]
public async Task Api_Put_Valid_Entity_Calls_ContextMethods_And_Returns_UpdatedODataResult(long Key)
{
    //arrange
    var data = new List<Org>
    {
        new Org { Id = 1, Name = "Name1", TaxCountryCode = "T1", TaxNumber = "TaxNumber1", CreatedBy = 1, CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, ModifiedBy = 1, ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now, Accounts = null, ChargeRequestsFromMe = null, ChargeRequestsToMe = null, PaymentRequestsFromMe = null, PaymentRequestsToMe = null, Submissions = null },
        new Org { Id = 2, Name = "Name2", TaxCountryCode = "T2", TaxNumber = "TaxNumber2", CreatedBy = 1, CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, ModifiedBy = 1, ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now, Accounts = null, ChargeRequestsFromMe = null, ChargeRequestsToMe = null, PaymentRequestsFromMe = null, PaymentRequestsToMe = null, Submissions = null },
        new Org { Id = 3, Name = "Name3", TaxCountryCode = "T3", TaxNumber = "TaxNumber3", CreatedBy = 1, CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, ModifiedBy = 1, ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now, Accounts = null, ChargeRequestsFromMe = null, ChargeRequestsToMe = null, PaymentRequestsFromMe = null, PaymentRequestsToMe = null, Submissions = null },
        new Org { Id = 4, Name = "Name4", TaxCountryCode = "T4", TaxNumber = "TaxNumber4", CreatedBy = 1, CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, ModifiedBy = 1, ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now, Accounts = null, ChargeRequestsFromMe = null, ChargeRequestsToMe = null, PaymentRequestsFromMe = null, PaymentRequestsToMe = null, Submissions = null },
        new Org { Id = 5, Name = "Name5", TaxCountryCode = "T5", TaxNumber = "TaxNumber5", CreatedBy = 1, CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, ModifiedBy = 1, ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now, Accounts = null, ChargeRequestsFromMe = null, ChargeRequestsToMe = null, PaymentRequestsFromMe = null, PaymentRequestsToMe = null, Submissions = null }
    }.AsQueryable();

    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Org>>();
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Org>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Org>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Org>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Org>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => data.GetEnumerator());
    mockSet.Setup(m => m.Find(It.IsAny<object[]>())).Returns<object[]>(ids => data.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == (int)ids[0]));            

    var mockContext = new Mock<MyDbContext>();
    mockContext.Setup(m => m.Orgs).Returns(mockSet.Object);
    mockContext.Setup(m => m.SaveChangesAsync()).Returns(() => Task.Run(() => { return 1; })).Verifiable();
    mockContext.Setup(m => m.MarkAsModified(It.IsAny<Org>())).Verifiable();

    Org entity = new Org
    {
        Id = Key,
        Name = "Put Org",
        TaxCountryCode = "Put" + Key.ToString(),
        TaxNumber = "Put" + Key.ToString()
    };

    var sut = new OrgsController(mockContext.Object);

    //act
    var actionResult = await sut.Put(Key, entity) as UpdatedODataResult<Org>;

    //assert
    mockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChangesAsync(), Times.Once());
    mockContext.Verify(m => m.MarkAsModified(entity), Times.Once());
    Assert.IsType<UpdatedODataResult<Org>>(actionResult);
    Assert.Equal(entity.Name, actionResult.Entity.Name);
    Assert.Equal(entity.TaxCountryCode, actionResult.Entity.TaxCountryCode);
    Assert.Equal(entity.TaxNumber, actionResult.Entity.TaxNumber);
}
```

Comment: ah cool, I glad to see that my old answer is still relevant and helps to other people in the community... please mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: I have a bit more to work through before I have the complete answer.  I'm working through the exception handling logic for DbUpdateConcurrencyException.  Mocking the Find method on my DBSet is proving to be more challenging than I anticipated.

Comment: I'd like to extend an enthusiastic thank you for this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460893/dbset-mock-no-results-while-calling-tolist-secondly.  This gave me the missing piece I needed.  I'll update and accept the answer as soon as I've updated my unit tests.